# Problems optimizing a likelihood function in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to maximize the log-likelihood $y_1 \log(p_1) + (1-y_1)\log(p_1) + y_2\log(p_2) + (1-y_2)\log(p_2)$. I have data on success of an experiment. Y identifies if person died or not, and X identifies control or treatment group.

What's wrong with my code?

```
# MLE for the likelihood
y <- c(rep(1,39), rep(0,674-39), rep(1,22), rep(0,680-22))
x <- c(rep(0, 674), rep(1, 680))

binom.ll <- function(theta, y, x) {
  y[x==0]*log(theta[1]) + (1-y[x==0])*log(1-theta[1])) + y[x==1]*log(theta[2]) + (1-y[x==1])*log(1-theta[2]))
}

theta.start <- c(0, 0)
ml.res <- nlm(binom.ll, theta.start, print.level=1, y=y, x=x, hessian=T)
ml.res

iteration = 0
Step:
[1] 0 0
Parameter:
[1] 0 0
Function Value
[1] 1.797693e+308
Gradient:
[1] -Inf    0

Error in nlm(binom.ll, theta.start, print.level = 1, y = y, x = x, hessian = T): non-finite value supplied by 'nlm'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In nlm(binom.ll, theta.start, print.level = 1, y = y, x = x, hessian = T): NA/Inf replaced by maximum positive value
2: In nlm(binom.ll, theta.start, print.level = 1, y = y, x = x, hessian = T): NA/Inf replaced by maximum positive value
```

Comment: Shouldn't `binom.ll` return a scalar? Right now it is trying to add vectors of different lengths (and you have mismatching parenthesis in multiple places). Also note that `log(0)` is not finite so you might want to start at `(0.5, 0.5)`.

Comment: In fact, I want binom.ll to return a vector: the MLE for group 1 and MLE for group 2. I am trying to compare the proportion of two groups. That's why my log-likelihood function is the sum of two binomial functions. You are right about the log(0). Thanks!

Comment: I confirm your function needs to return a scalar, otherwise what is there to maximize? Also note that `nlm` does a minimization so you'll have to negate your objective function.

Comment: Ok, so maybe I'm not understanding how this is working. Can you help me fixing the code? I have two independent samples of subjects, the control group and the treatment group. I want to compare the proportion of sick subjects in the control and treatment groups. Am I writing the likelihood correctly? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you want to try to simultaneously minimize both `x*theta` and `(1-x)*(1-theta)` . I would recommend moving this to stats.stackexchange to get some advice on algorithms to evaluate experiments of this sort.   Meanwhile, have you looked at alternative approaches, such as  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085361/r-optim-nlm-with-multidimensional-array-of-parameters?rq=1  ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume $p_1 = \mathbb P(Y=1 | X=0)$ and $p_2 = \mathbb P (Y=1|X=1)$.

The log-likelihood you want to maximize is
$$ n_{10} \log p_1 + n_{00} \log(1-p_1) + n_{11} \log p_2 + n_{01} \log(1-p_2) $$
where $n_{ij}$ is the number of observations with $Y=i, X=j$.

You can do that directly, no need for numerical optimization. The optimum is $p_1 = {n_{10} \over n_{10} + n_{00}}$ and $p_2 = {n_{11} \over n_{11} + n_{01}}$.

Edit: if you really want R code, here it is.

```
y <- c(rep(1,39), rep(0,674-39), rep(1,22), rep(0,680-22))
x <- c(rep(0, 674), rep(1, 680))

binom.ll <- function(theta, y, x) 
{
  n <- table(y,x);
  th <- matrix( c(1-theta,theta), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE);
  return( -sum(n*log(th)) );
}


> theta.start <- c(0.5, 0.5)
> nlm(binom.ll, theta.start, y=y, x=x, hessian=T)
$minimum
[1] 246.1096

$estimate
[1] 0.05786353 0.03235302

$gradient
[1] -0.0002950512 -0.0004371658

$hessian
        [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 12323.5     0.00
[2,]     0.0 21591.73

$code
[1] 2

$iterations
[1] 21

Il y a eu 28 avis (utilisez warnings() pour les visionner)

> 39/674
[1] 0.0578635
> 22/680
[1] 0.03235294
```